# TextMeshPro Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, text, unity-game-engine

**EDIT: Solved. Used `TextMeshProUGUI` instead of `TextMeshPro`.**

**Background:**
I'm using TextMeshPro to display text. I want to change the text via a script. The problem is I get a NullReferenceException when I attempt to change it.

**Details:**

My script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class UI_speed : MonoBehaviour {

    TextMeshPro textmeshPro;

    void Start () {
        textmeshPro = GetComponent<TextMeshPro>();
        textmeshPro.text = "test";
    }
}
```

The code matches the [TextMeshPro API](http://digitalnativestudios.com/textmeshpro/docs/ScriptReference/TextMeshPro-text.html) so I'm not sure what's going on. I'm using Unity 5.6.1f1. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.
[image: My workstation]

Answer (score 15):

Found a solution. Used `TextMeshProUGUI` instead of `TextMeshPro`. Unsure of the details but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
textmeshPro = GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshPro>();
```

Answer (score -2):

Go to **Component->UI->Legacy->Text** to insert textbox instead striving hard with TextMeshPro

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. User is trying to use TextMeshPro which is superior to the legacy system. Just because there's a null reference in a script, doesn't mean you should just give up and encourage the use of legacy tools.